# .htaccess rewrite url remove CSS,JS,AND IMAGES Whatever i do its not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Ive seen all posts on stackoverflow, and what ever i see i dont get an answere.
im using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule profile/username/(.*)/ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule profile/username/(.*) profile.php?username=$1
```

and im my profile,php head im using these tags:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><?php echo ucwords($profileData->first_name); ?> - Facebook</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
<base href="index.php" />
```

What ever i do its still not working please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are rewriting rules, you need also to rewrite base href HTML, or just add the full url to your styles,js and images.
Example base href:

```
   <head>
    <base href="https://www.yourwebsite.com/">
   </head>
```

Comment: yes i found why this was happening tough thanks very much! What i did made the assets/../.. into test/assets/.../..test/assets/../.. So i just made them all to my http:localhots/test/assets/.../.. and its now working!

Comment: You have to be careful, because if you create a new rule that will be for example profile/username/activity then you need to move them one more time ../ , if you want to be more independent , just try with the base href or add the full url to your href attributes.